# How to loop Audio without a delay in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, expo

I am currently trying to loop an audio (.mp3) file using Expo AV module like below:

```
  await soundObject.loadAsync(assets[0], {
        isLooping: true
  });

  await soundObject.playAsync();
```

The audio loops as expected except that instead of looping immediately, it stops for about 1 sec after the track ends, and then starts again. For my application, it is important for the audio loop to seem like a continuous sound.

I trimmed the audio down using the Audacity software to make sure there is no extra silence. The audio file loops perfectly fine without any delay in both Garageband and Audacity. But when I loop it in my application, it seems like you are stopping and playing the file again and again.

Are there any workarounds to this? I have so far tried this on my iOS device in the expo Go app.